# Populating multiple div's in a loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a tab control with a bunch of check boxes on it (potentially more than I have shown here). I create the checkboxes in a loop like this:

```
<div id="mechanical" class="tabcontent">
    <% for (int i = 0; i < Model.MechanicalRisks.Count; i++)
       {%>
    <%= Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.MechanicalRisks[i].IsChecked)%>
    <%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.MechanicalRisks[i].Text)%>
    <br />
    <%} %>
    <br />
    Other:
    <br />
    <%= Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.OtherMechanical, new { style = "width:100%;" })%>
</div>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

I don't like how the check boxes continue down the left side. I would prefer them to be in multiple columns, so if there were say twenty boxes, it would not be stupid tall. If I were to create multiple div's for columns inside the tab, how would I go about dividing the checkboxes among the div's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more a styling issue than a C#/ ASP.NET MVC 2 issue

```
<ul>
<% for (int i = 0; i < Model.MechanicalRisks.Count; i++) {%>
<li>
    <%=Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.MechanicalRisks[i].IsChecked)%>
    <%=Html.DisplayFor(x => x.MechanicalRisks[i].Text)%>
</li>
<%} %>
</ul>
<br />
Other:<br />
<%= Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.OtherMechanical, new { style = "width:100%;" })%>
```

Then create some new style or build off of `#mechanical`

```
#mechanical li
{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding this correctly but I don't see how this gets multiple columns. It just makes it into a list.

Comment: The CSS style below makes it into 2 columns

Comment: great answer, learn something new every day.  You can change the width to say 25% to get 4 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Add two divs each for displaying a column, within each div have a for loop.  The first loop will display the first half of the records and the second loop will display the second half of the records.

Comment: Yeah, I'd rather not hard code limits inside the loop. Plus, this will create a new div for each check box.

Comment: Well i did say it was off the top of my head :)  Do you have any idea how many checkboxes you want to display, what would you want to happen if you run out of width for the new columns?

Comment: Haha it's cool. But no I don't really know for sure. It's not many right now, but this will be driven from a database eventually so that will be up to somebody else. My thought was like yours. I could divide the count by two to get an even number in two div's, but I don't know how to dynamically fill them.

Comment: well you could have two divs, column 1 and 2.  Within each div have a loop.  Take the total count of items and divide by two.  Then the first loop could start from 0 to half way mark and the second for start from the half way mark and display the rest, what do you reckon?

Comment: I reckon it's better than it is now. Still feels a little dirty to me, but I'll try it out and see how it suits me.